# Проблема с запуском open server

Tags: openserver

2017-01-05 00:03:26  --------------------------------------------
2017-01-05 00:03:26  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2017-01-05 00:03:26  Файл C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts недоступен для записи
2017-01-05 00:03:26  Отключите использование HOSTS файла или настройте права доступа
2017-01-05 00:03:26  Сбой запуска!
Что делать, чтобы исправить?

Comment: запустите openserver с правами администратора.

Comment: это как? есть только просто запустить

Comment: правой кнопкой мыши, во всплывающем меню выберите сий пункт

Comment: да я имел в виду, что после запуска, когда появляется красный флажок существует только запуск и я забыл сначала про запуск самой программы

Answer (score 25):

Минимум два пути:

1. Запуск от самого сервера от имени администратора, как и обычные программы:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Надо нажать правой кнопкой мыши на программе и во всплывающем меню выберите сий пункт......
2. В новых версиях (как минимум  5.2.2 точно, может и раньше) можно поставить галочку *Не вносить изменения в HOSTS файл* в настройках *OpenServer* на вкладке `Сервер`

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Если поставить галочку не вносить изменения в HOSTS файл, то сайты перестанут отображаться по домену, можно расширить права, команда в cmd: attrib.exe -s -r -h -a C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 2):

Причины сбоя обычно происходят когда ставите некие доп программы:(Avact cleanUp; Kerish Doctor... ) которые блокируют изменения в hosts.
 Есть 2  решения:

1) Кликаем по Open Server x64.exe ПКМ и заходим в свойство\ совместимость *запускать от имени администратора:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) но если хотите чтобы ваши сайты отображались в C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
просто копируем его содержимое и создаём заново файл: hosts

PS. создать файл: hosts  по указанному пути возможно не получимся. Его нужно создать например на рабочем столе и перенести с правами администратора! После этого все локальные сайты будут видны в hosts

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема может возникнуть с отсутствием файла hosts в директории C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc